# I can't see window of application, what I've lauched.

Tags: windows-7

I installed CrypTool (to cryptography education application). I used it before, but when I turn on again, I see app is lauched, but I can't see window. So I decided to reinstall app. I did it, but reinstallation brought nothing.

Comment: I have a similar issue. The window is on screen and I can even interact with it but it's not visible. Like it's not rendering or something.

Answer (score 2):

Is there an associated button in the taskbar for the window, yet it is not on-screen? If that's the case, then it probably was moved off the screen completely, somehow. Sometimes this can happen (for example, if you switch from a 2 monitor setup to a single monitor setup). To move it back into view, right click the toolbar button and select move. Press an arrow key to initiate moving, and then move the mouse. The window will jump right under the mouse pointer. Click once to finish moving it and it should remain visible again.

Answer (score 0):

There’s several things you can try:

- Try <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> to switch to the window. Sometimes a window will be removed from the Taskbar, but will reappear if you switch to it
- Open the Task Manager and see if it is still running. If so, try switching to it in the *Applications* tab by clicking it and clicking *Switch To*
- Next, try killing the program and running it again (Task Manager->Processes)
- Use a program like [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) to find the window (expand WinSpy, select the process in the *All Windows* pane, find the program’s main window, and right-click it to select `Visible`)
- Try reinstalling it *after* making sure that it is not running, otherwise it will look like it has no effect

Comment: It's great and exhaustive, but I've checked everything and still not work